# RabbitMQ C# Practical Example

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, visual-studio-2017

I am new to RabbitMQ and am having trouble finding a VS2017 C# example that does more that prints to the Console.  I can send and receive messages no problem, but I would like to take the contents of the message and actually use it.  Below is the code I have:

```
using System.Text;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
using System.IO;

namespace MyCode
{
  class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "xxx.xx.x.x", UserName = "MyTest", Password = "MyTest", Port = 5672 };
      using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
      {
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {

          channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "MyTest", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

          var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
          consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
          {
            var body = ea.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            DoSomething(message);
          };

          channel.BasicConsume(queue: "MyTest", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
        }
      }
    }
    static void DoSomething(string message)
    {
      File.AppendAllText(@"C:\RMQ.txt", message);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, I can't ever seem to get anything out of the Consumer.Received step.  Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT::

I was able to make it work by using this code instead:

```
  var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "xxx.xx.x.x", UserName = "MyTest", Password = "MyTest", Port = 5672 };
  using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
  {
    using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {

      channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "MyTest", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

      BasicGetResult consumer = channel.BasicGet("MyTest", true);

      if (consumer != null)
      {
        string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(consumer.Body);
        DoSomething(message);
      }

    }
  }
```

Anybody see any issues with this?

Comment: Why can't DoSomething contain code to do the thing you want to do?

Comment: And who does send the message? Also, if you try to set the breakpoint into the body of the lambda assigned to `consumer.Received`, does your execution flow break on it?

Comment: I want DoSomething to do the code I want.  The problem is that the code never reaches there.  The code will break on the lambda statement (the entire thing), but will then step to the end of the using instead of going into the DoSomething.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your first piece of code is that your program finishes execution before it can handle any messages. `EventingBasedConsumer` is asynchronous and won't actually prevent you program from exiting. You need to implement a wait of some sort to be able to actually handle messages. Try adding `Thread.Sleep(10000);` just after `Channel.BasicConsume` and check if there are any messages being processed.

Comment: How is this suppose to continue listen for events in a web application?

Answer (score 0):

For fire and forget applications, that tries to setup the read, try not to use the "using" statement for your connection and channel.  They will go out of scope (set for garbage collection) once the the subroutine finish the execution.

Obviously, you need to have the console application up and running to receive the message.  So, I did put a Console.Readline() in the calling app to prevent the thread from exiting.